# function override error in .razor.cs, but not in .razor

Tags: c#, inheritance, razor, overriding, blazor

In the blazor project, I've created a `public class BaseComponent : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase`

And so I want some of my components that are a bit complex to inherit from this class.

Now, I've added an error page, and I see some inconsistency when overriding the function `OnInitialized`, but it seems this is not limited to only that function.

Here's the `Error.razor` file that compiles without errors:

```
@inherits BaseComponent
@code {

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();
    }
}
```

And when I want to move all the code to `Error.razor.cs` file:

```
using WebApp.Shared;

namespace WebApp.Pages.Error
{
    public partial class Error : BaseComponent
    {
        protected override void OnInitialized() // error is here
        {
            base.OnInitialized();
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error saying: `'Error.OnInitialized()': no suitable method found to override`.

I've tried making the `Error.razor.cs` partial class inherit from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase` instead from my `BaseComponent` that also inherits this class and has an override of `OnInitialized` function itself, and it doesn't give any compile errors.

So my question is:
Why are there no compilation errors in the `.razor` file, but there are in `.razor.cs` file?

Comment: This code works fine, the problem is not in this example code but somewhere else. Try clearing and reloading the solution, sometimes works if running an older Blazor version.

Comment: Ad if that doesn't work: see how many BaseComponent classes you have. IntelliSense can add a dummy very quickly.

Comment: If the code works when it's in the razor file, but not when you create a code behind file and move `OnInitialized` into it, then it's likely the compiler is not linking the two correctly.  Are the namespaces for the two the same?  Define `@namespace WebApp.Pages` in the razor file and the code behind file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example base component and usage that you may wish to use as a template.

Note:

1. I've made the base component a class not a razor component.  Any child will almost certainly overwrite the content.
2. I've set the base class as `abstract` so it can't be used directly.
3. I've set the Namespace in everything.

```cs
// Components/MyComponentBase.cs
namespace StackOverflowAnswers.Components
{
    public abstract class MyComponentBase : ComponentBase
    {
        [Parameter] [EditorRequired] public string Header { get; set; } = String.Empty;

        [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }   
    }
}
```

```
// Components/MyDiv.razor
@namespace StackOverflowAnswers.Components
@inherits MyComponentBase

<h3>@this.Header</h3>
<div class="m-2">
    @this.ChildContent
</div>
```

```cs
// Components/MyDiv.razor.cs
namespace StackOverflowAnswers.Components
{
    public partial class MyDiv : MyComponentBase 
    {
        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            base.OnInitialized();
        }
    }
}
```

And usage in *Index.razor*

```
@page "/"
@page "/Index"
@using StackOverflowAnswers

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />
<StackOverflowAnswers.Components.MyDiv Header = "Hello Blazor">
    My Div Content
</StackOverflowAnswers.Components.MyDiv>
```